# Don't allow role to delete published content even its their own

Tags: 8, users

thanks for reading my question.

I am currently working on Drupal 8 site, please consider the following roles:

```
Admin - Can do everything
Publisher - can do everything the Admin can do, except set up and edit new 
administrators 
Editor - Can do everything the publisher can do, except Publish content to live
Writer - Can do everything the Editor can do, except Delete published content
```

I have managed to satisfy the permission for the roles `Admin`, `Publisher`, and `Editor`, now it seems the `Writer` one is tricky.

The only option seems like to `Enable Delete own content` for `Writer`, but that won't solve the issue if his article was already published, he can delete it.

Is there a module that can be solved by this? Or a better approach on how to configure permissions?

Regards,

Comment: But I guess they should be able to delete *unpublished* content? I assume you need a custom implementation of hook_node_access() then that returns AccessResult::forbidden() if the operation is edit, the node is published and the user doesn't have hte administer nodes permission or something like that

Comment: @Berdir yup, they should be able to delete _unpublished_ own content

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Simply search for and disable the permission "Delete any content" for any / all content types for the role of "writer".

This is also a very handy module to help you find permissions https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_filter

Comment: but they should be able to delete their own unpublished content